# Create new list

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following list :

```
[["Accounts"],["Budget Propane"],[""],[""],[""],["Laser AMP"],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""]]
```

With a general function, how could I parse that list in such a way new list will become `[account1, account2]`?

So I need the remove all the subempty lists and the element `[Accounts]`.

```js
function isBlank(line) {
  return line[0].trim() === '';
}

function parseData(data) {

  const output = [];

  data.forEach(function(line, index) {
    if (isBlank(line) || index === 0) {
      return;
    }

    output.push(line[0])
  });

  return output;
}

console.log(parseData([["Accounts"],["Budget Propane"],[""],[""],[""],["Laser AMP"],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""]]));
```

Comment: Here is what I have done so far.

Comment: It looks like it should work, assuming a correct definition of `isBlank()`. What problem are you having?

Comment: What is `currentGroupName` for?

Comment: @Barmar No, it is not working, that's why I need your help.

Comment: Just as a heads up ..  Try to put your code in **at the time you ask** the question, instead of **after you ask** to avoid downvotes.  S.O. mods and users find it a waste of time when they get into a question only to find quarter of the info is there .. I upvoted for editing and including your code and explanation.

Comment: @Zak Yes, I've seen that :( I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Is `Accounts` meant to be a string, or is it a variable?

Comment: Your code works fine. Click on Run code snippet and see.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.reduce((acc, val, idx) => (idx !== 0 && val.length && val[0]) ? acc.concat(val) : acc, []);
```

this is standard list flattening with a filter, which is inherently a reduce operation.  A reduce takes a list and reduces it into a single value, in this case a flattened list since it's taking a list of lists.

you seem new to js so to walk you through this... im starting with myList, which is your array, and im running the array operation "reduce" on it, which does what I explained above.  the first argument to reduce is a function, called a reducer, to run on each item in the original array, the function takes several arguments, the first argument to the reducer is the "accumulated value" named acc in this case, this is the final value reduce will give you, the second named "val" is the current item in the list I'm operating on, and the 3rd in this case is the current index since we need it for our filter.

All i do in my reducer is 1st check that the index isn't 0, then than the current item has a length (0 counts as not having a length) and then that the value of the first item in the current item is "truthy" (empty strings are falsey).  If all of those are true, i concatenate the current item to my accumulated value, concat just makes 1 list out of 2.  if any are false, i just skip that item.  The final argument to reduce is the starting value, in this case an empty array.

edit: edited to filter out items that are lists with a single blank entry.

Comment: What about removing the first element?

Comment: missed that, fixed

Comment: @Andy `filter()` returns the elements of the original array. If you need to transform the elements while filtering, you need `reduce`.

Comment: you could filter it first, but the reduce achieves the overall goal faster since i can build the filter logic into the reduce easily and cleanly in this case

Comment: @Andy `reduce` allows you to do `filter` + `map` in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parseList = function(list){
  var result = [];
  for(var l2 of list){
    for(var el of l2){
      if(el !== Accounts) result.push(el);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

or

```
list.map(el => el.length ? el[0] : el).filter(el => !Array.isArray(el) && el !== Accounts);
```